# How to modify the html css dom with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Here's my question:
Is there a way to modify a css file while only using javascript?

Comment: Ah.. the titlegore.. How are we supposed to help you with a description like that?

Comment: Hi, sorry I would like to know how
you can change the css html5
elements using pure javascript? I
would like to know the inner
workings of libraries as jequery
which one of its functions is to
modify (see) the elements css

Comment: @Sommer: What research have you done? This is a really basic question with examples to be found in abundance online. Did you bother doing a basic Google search?

Answer (score 5):

there are so many ways you can do it.

1- only js.

```
document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
```

2- using jquery

```
$("#id").css( "color", "red" );
```

Answer (score 1):

you mean using pure javascript? if so, see below for examples

```
 document.getElementById('id').style.display='block'
 document.getElementsByClassName('class')[0].style.marginleft='25px'
```

Comment: it should be marginLeft instead of marginleft (camelCase)